# How can I extract a range of rows from in a matrix finding specific characters?

Tags: r, matrix, extract

If i have this a matrix of this type:

```
V1...................V2
"Mateo"..............1
"Marcos".............2 
"Lucas"..............3
"Juan"...............4
"Felipe".............5
"Federicus"..........6
```

The idea is to create a new matrix of the same type using the column V1, for example to extract from second to forth row asking:

```
If V1= "Marcos" & V1="Felipe"
```

then display from Marcos to Felipe:

```
V1...................V2
"Marcos".............2 
"Lucas"..............3
"Juan"...............4
"Felipe".............5
```

Comment: Use `which` to find the range and with `seq`, get the sequence.  Something like this should work `i1 <- with(df1, match(c("Marcos", "Felipe"), V1)); df1[i1[1]:i1[2],]`.   I assume it as a data.frame

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` to get the index and then with `:` get the sequence

```
i1 <- with(df1, match(c("Marcos", "Felipe"), V1))
df1[i1[1]:i1[2],]
#      V1 V2
#2 Marcos  2
#3  Lucas  3
#4   Juan  4
#5 Felipe  5
```

Here this assumes that there are no duplicate names.  Also, `%in%` is non-specific as it doesn't distinguish the names.

Comment: What if `"Felipe"` comes before `"Marcos"`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas  Then, the match vector would be flipped

Answer (score 1):

When one of names is more than once in `V1`, `match` will only return the first value. But it should return all. See also adapted example at end answer. You can solve it with `which` and `range`.

With:

```
r <- which(df$V1 %in% c("Marcos","Felipe"))
df[Reduce(':', range(r)),]
```

you get:

```
      V1 V2
2 Marcos  2
3  Lucas  3
4 Felipe  5
5   Juan  4
6 Felipe  5
```

Adapted example:

```
df <- read.table(text="Mateo 1
Marcos 2 
Lucas 3
Felipe 5
Juan 4
Felipe 5
Federicus 6", header=FALSE)
```